# Show that for a non square positive integer $d$, there exists a rational number $x/y$ such that $\vert \sqrt{d} - x/y\vert < 1/2y^2$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have been given that $d > 0$ is an integer, which is not a complete square. How do I prove that there exists a rational number $\frac{x}{y}$ such that $$\left\vert \sqrt{d} - \frac{x}{y}\right\vert < \frac{1}{2y^2}$$

The questions says to use Dirichlet's Unit Theorem as a hint.

I've been wracking my brains, but have no idea on how to start. Any hints that you guys can give me on how to apply Dirichlet's Unit Theorem to this problem?

Comment: Are you sure the hint is to use Dirichlet's *unit* theorem and not his [approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem)?

Comment: Yes, it says the unit theorem. Now I'm beginning to think it might be a typo. Given that this question is clearly indirectly asking for a proof of  the approximation theorem. Do you concur? There's also the fact that the left hand side of the inequality has 2 in the denominator, unlike the approximation theorem

Comment: My previous comment was a bit haphazard. It probably follows from the approximation theorem, but note that this is an improvement on it (the error is $1/2y^2$ instead of $1/y^2$).

Comment: Maybe the unit theorem tells you there's a unit in ${\bf Z}[\sqrt d]$, which says $x^2-dy^2=1$ has solutions. Not every solution satisfies the inequality you're asked for, but one can prove that out of every pair of consecutive solutions at least one satisfies the inequality.

Comment: There's still the matter of the $2$ in the denominator

Comment: I'm aware of that, junk – I did write, "not every solution satisfies the inequality you've asked for." But I went on to note that "out of every pair of consecutive solutions at least one satisfies the inequality." Prove that, and you win.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually holds for all real numbers, not only for those of the form $\sqrt{d}$. In fact Hurwitz had shown that there are infinitely many rationals satisfy the inequality even when one replaces the constant $2$ by $\sqrt{5}$ on the right side, so the statement in your question is comparatively much weaker.

A standard proof of the proposition(and also the Hurwitz's theorem) makes use of the theory of continued fractions, but since you are asking for a proof using Dirichlet's unit theorem, I'd like to say a few more words. As @Gerry Myerson pointed out, the unit theorem gives rise to infinitely many integral solutions to the Pell's equation  $x^2-dy^2=\pm1$. Then since
$$\frac{1}{y^2}=\left|\frac{x^2}{y^2}-d\right|=\left|\frac{x}{y}-\sqrt{d}\right|\cdot\left|\frac{x}{y}+\sqrt{d}\right|$$ 
the task is reduced to finding a unit $x+y\sqrt{d}\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ such that $x/y+\sqrt{d}>2$. It turns out that there are infinitely many such units for each $d$, as when $x,y$ being taken large enough, the rational $x/y$ is getting closer and closer to $\sqrt{d}$.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Phil. Z's excellent answer, I'd like to mention that the solution is quite straightforward with a bit of knowledge of continued fractions.

Indeed, suppose that $\sqrt{d}$ has continued fraction expansion $[a_0; a_1,a_2,\dotsc]$ and let $x_n / y_n = [a_0; a_1, \dotsc, a_n]$ be a convergent of $\sqrt{d}$. It is a standard result in the theory of continued fractions that
$$
\frac{1}{y_n (y_{n+1} + y_n)}
< \left\lvert \sqrt{d} - \frac{x_n}{y_n} \right\rvert
< \frac{1}{y_n y_{n+1}}.
$$
From the recursive formula $y_{n+1} = a_{n+1} y_n + y_{n-1}$ and the fact that $y_n \geq 1$ for every $n \geq 0$, it follows that we're done if we can find at least one $n$ for which $a_n \geq 2$. But this is the case because:

1. $\sqrt{d}$ is irrational since $d$ isn't a square, hence it's continued fraction expansion is infinite;
2. the expansion $[1;1,1,\dotsc]$ corresponds to the golden ratio, which isn't of the form $\sqrt{d}$.